# Lookup a Cell which Contains a Part of Other Cell - Searching Upwards

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm stuck on this excel problem and have searched for a solution with no avail. Hopefully you can help!

In Column A I have a list of customers and in Column B I have an even longer list of Invoices. Basically what I am trying to do is match the most recent invoice to the customer. I tried using `=INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1,IF(ISERR(FIND(A1,B:B)),0,1),0))` This formula searches for Customer 1's name in the list of invoices, and brings back the first invoice it finds to C1.

This formula works wonderfully -  as long as the customer has only one invoice. After that the formula is useless because I need the most recent invoice, not the first one it finds.

What I am trying to accomplish is in the table below. Notice that Customer 4 has Invoice #002 and #003, and I need the most recent (or the one closest to the bottom) matched to that customer.

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Customers      Invoices                      Recent Invoice            |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Customer 1     [Invoice #001] Customer 3     [Invoice #004] Customer 1 |
| Customer 2     [Invoice #002] Customer 4     N/A                       |
| Customer 3     [Invoice #003] Customer 4     [Invoice #001] Customer 3 |
| Customer 4     [Invoice #004] Customer 1     [Invoice #003] Customer 4 | 
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

It seemed so simple to me... start at the bottom and search upwards... but I guess it's not so simple.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

-J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will find the last entry for each customer:

```
=INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($B$2:INDEX(B:B,MATCH("zzz",B:B)))/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,$B$2:INDEX(B:B,MATCH("zzz",B:B))))),1))
```

If you want the second to last change the last `1` to `2`.

Comment: Wow this worked great! And you read my mind with the ability to search for the second to last. Thanks so much!!

Comment: @Joseph please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.